# substring of variable length

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, substring

I have a table with a column which contains strings like below.

```
RTSPP_LZ_AEN
RTSPP_LZ_CPS
RTSPP_LZ_HOUSTON
RTSPP_LZ_LCRA
RTSPP_LZ_NORTH
RTSPP_LZ_RAYBN
RTSPP_LZ_SOUTH
RTSPP_LZ_WEST
RTSPP_BTE_CC1 
RTSPP_BTE_PUN1 
RTSPP_BTE_PUN2
```

I need to get the substring from the second occurrence of `_` till the end of string and as you can see the substring is not of fixed length. The first part is not always fixed it can change. As of now I am using the following code to achieve it.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING([String],CHARINDEX('_',[String],(CHARINDEX('_',[String])+1))+1,100)
FROM [Table]
```

As you can see I am taking an arbitrary large value as the length to take care of variable length. Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Will there always be exactly 2 underscores?

Comment: Is the first part always RTSPP_LZ_ or could have other values?

Comment: @AaronBertrand As of now I have not encountered a case with more than 2 underscores. It might occur in the future in such a case the last underscore till the end of string. A more generic solution which can handle the nth occurrence of underscore would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @NenadZivkovic Not always the case they can change like RTSPP_BTE_CC1
RTSPP_BTE_PUN1
RTSPP_BTE_PUN2

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `CHARINDEX` in combination with [`REVERSE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180040.aspx) function to find last occurrence of `_`, and you can use [`RIGHT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx) to get the specified number of characters from the end of string.

```
SELECT RIGHT([String],CHARINDEX('_',REVERSE([String]),0)-1)
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/761f7/1)**

Answer (score 8):

You can try giving len([string]) as the last argument :

```
 SELECT SUBSTRING([String],CHARINDEX('_',[String],(CHARINDEX('_',[String])+1))+1,len([string])) FROM [Table]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a common table expression to do the job like the code below. The gives the added flexibility to get all sub strings no matter how many underscores are in the string.

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
      0 AS row
      ,CHARINDEX('_', [String]) pos
      ,[String] 
    FROM [Table]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
      row + 1
      ,CHARINDEX('_', [String], pos + 1)
      ,[String]
    FROM cte
    WHERE pos > 0
)
SELECT 
    row
    ,[String]
    ,pos
    ,SUBSTRING([String], pos + 1, LEN([String]) -pos)
FROM cte 
WHERE pos > 0
-- Remove line below to see all possible substrs
  AND row = 1
ORDER BY 
  [String], pos
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer and it handles even the case when there are zero underscores but I can't use a CTE as this is a small part of a much bigger query

Answer (score 1):

This seems nice to me:

```
declare @yourvariable nvarchar(max)

set @yourvariable=(Select
(SELECT  distinct ','+yourcolumn
from yourtable 
for xml path('')) )

select substring(@yourvariable,2,len(@yourvariable))
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, even this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING([String],CHARINDEX('_',[String],(CHARINDEX('_',[String])+1))+1,
             LEN([String])-CHARINDEX('_',[String])+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also this seems more neat and consice:

```
Select substring(yourtemp.yourcolumn,2,len(yourtemp.yourcolumn)) as yourcolumn
from(
select(
SELECT  distinct ','+yourcolumn
from yourtable
for xml path('') ) as yourcolumn) as yourtemp
```