# trim characters from string of one field and fill a new field for each record in SQL table

Tags: sql-server

I added a new field "StrikePrice" to my existing table "OS1115".
I need to trim some characters from an existing field "symbol" and enter that into the new field.
I know I can do this:

```
UPDATE OS1115 SET StrikePrice = RIGHT(symbol, 4)
```

But the problem is that the amount of characters I need vary in length, but are always superseded by either a P or a C.
Here are a couple examples:

```
QQQ_112015C112.5
PCLN_112015P1287.5
NFLX_112015P107
```

I need to trim the numbers at the end of the string that come after the P or C and enter that in the new field. 
so in this case that would result in:
112.5
1287.5
107
How can I do this?
I use MS SQL Express 2012

Comment: Possible duplicate of [substring of variable length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975150/substring-of-variable-length)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work:

```
RIGHT(symbol, PATINDEX('%[cp]%', REVERSE(symbol))-1)
```

though I'm sure there are a variety of ways to do it.

Comment: Thanks much, that did it.

Answer (score 0):

You got one answer while I was testing mine. Here's another way:

substring(StrikePrice,charindex('C',StrikePrice,6)+charindex('P',StrikePrice,6)+1,99)