# How to count string between string in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data that having different length of value.

For example I have 2 rows of data:

```
 CL-CI/PST/102/VII/2016
 CL-CI/PST/0102/VII/2016
```

The difference between them is 102 (3 digits) and 0102 (4 digits)

I want in my SQL checking:

```
if (3Digits)
begin
    ....
end
else
begin
    ....
end
```

The records of data format is not fixed. Just not fixed on this string **VII/2016** (based on month in roman numerals/year).

I know how to count the string is using **LEN**. But my problem is when I select top 1 of data. In this top 1 data that I got, I want to check dynamically if it is 4 digits / 3 digits that I got from that top 1. I'm stuck on this.

Comment: Is this a fixed format or the format of data may differ from record to record?

Comment: For this string VII/2016 (based on month(roman numerals)/year) is not fixed

Comment: fixed is not a count of chars, fixed is that your string is between second `/` and third `/` like in this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975150/substring-of-variable-length

Comment: And what is there happening in that `if 3digits` block which is so specific enough for being separated from all other scenarios? Adding leading zero?

Comment: I want to make sequence no, but it depends on the last record that I got. For example I got  CL-CI/PST/102/VII/2016, so the next new seq number is  CL-CI/PST/0103/VII/2016. and when I select top 1 again for example I got CL-CI/SPG/069/VII/2016, so the next seq number must CL-CI/SPG/0068/VII/2016. The 3 digits data is the old format version from production. I have to change to 4 digits format. This format number is per-branch. That's why I want to check using if condition. But any idea will be welcome,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this

#### Easy: Just the length

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(100)='CL-CI/PST/0102/VII/2016';
SELECT LEN(CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@s,'/','</x><x>')+'</x>' AS XML).value('/x[3]','varchar(max)'))
```

The result is 4

#### setbased approach

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,YourString VARCHAR(100),OtherValue VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl(YourString,OtherValue) VALUES
 ('CL-CI/PST/102/VII/2016','With 3 digits')
,('CL-CI/PST/0102/VII/2016','With 4 digits');

WITH ExtendByPart3 AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(YourString,'/','</x><x>')+'</x>' AS XML).value('/x[3]','varchar(max)') AS Part3
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT *,LEN(Part3) AS LenPart3 FROM ExtendByPart3
```

The result

```
ID  YourString              OtherValue      Part3   LenPart3
1   CL-CI/PST/102/VII/2016  With 3 digits   102     3
2   CL-CI/PST/0102/VII/2016 With 4 digits   0102    4
```

Btw: There are several questions about: *How to access item X of a seperated string* and most answers come with very complex CTEs, loops, CLR methods... This approach is direct and **type safe**. Change the `nvarchar(max)` of the `.value()` function to `int` and you would get the number - if needed.

[I placed an answer to one of these questions myself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38275075/5089204), but - as this question is existing for years - the leading answers are very old fashioned and - IMO - outdated. But still it migth be worth reading this...

#### Retrieve all values

If you might be interested in your other values too, you could do this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,YourString VARCHAR(100),OtherValue VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl(YourString,OtherValue) VALUES
 ('CL-CI/PST/102/VII/2016','With 3 digits')
,('CL-CI/PST/0102/VII/2016','With 4 digits');

WITH Splitted AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(YourString,'/','</x><x>')+'</x>' AS XML) AS XMLData
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT XMLData.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)') AS Part1
      ,XMLData.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)') AS Part2
      ,XMLData.value('/x[3]','int') AS Number
      ,XMLData.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)') AS MonthRoman
      ,XMLData.value('/x[5]','int') AS TheYear
FROM Splitted
```

The result (attention: as returned as `int` the Number is without the leading zero)

```
Part1   Part2   Number  MonthRoman  TheYear
CL-CI   PST     102     VII         2016
CL-CI   PST     102     VII         2016
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `case` and `like` are sufficient:

```
select (case when col like '%/%/[0-9][0-9][0-9]/%' then <3 digit stuff>
             when col like '%/%/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/%' then <4 digit stuff>
        end)
```