# SQL Server 2016: get string between two characters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I have multiple records like this: `GUID-155_188.PNG`

I need to take the string `155`, of course this number is variable so there could be 1, 2, 3000, etc.

But the syntax is always the same, is between a `-` and a `_`.

So, how can I extract that part between these two characters?

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17975453/2516576)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A SQL Query to select a string between two known strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362260/a-sql-query-to-select-a-string-between-two-known-strings)

Comment: is not what i was expecting but i'm satisfied

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
DECLARE @g varchar(1000) = 'GUID-155_188.PNG'
SELECT LEFT(RIGHT(@g, CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(@g), 0) - 1), CHARINDEX('_', (RIGHT(@g, CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(@g), 0) - 1)), 0) - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(100) = 'GUID-15_188.PNG'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@string, CHARINDEX('-', @string) + 1, CHARINDEX('_', @string) - CHARINDEX('-', @string) - 1)
```