# Extract specific string from the text before certain value

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a values called

```
C:\ABC\BHDKJF\20240102\Files_20240102_newfile
```

Is there a way to extract value from last symbol `\`  in SQL?

The expected output is `Files_20240102_newfile`

Appreciate if anyone could help.

Comment: The usual trick is to find the \ in the reversed string, something like: `select right(N'C:\ABC\BHDKJF\20240102\Files_20240102_newfile',nullif(charindex('\', reverse('C:\ABC\BHDKJF\20240102\Files_20240102_newfile')),0) - 1)` the NULLIF trick protects when string doesn't contain \ at all

Comment: Does this answer your question? [substring of variable length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975150/substring-of-variable-length)

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you only want to Extract the last value.
try this

```
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE('C:\ABC\BHDKJF\20240102\Files_20240102_newfile'), 1, CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE('C:\ABC\BHDKJF\20240102\Files_20240102_newfile')) - 1)) AS extracted_filename;
```

Or replace another path which you want

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you need here is a utility function. One such function might be

```
create or alter function dbo.GetFilenameFromPath(@Path varchar(500))
returns varchar(200)
as
begin
  return (
    select Right(
      @Path, 
      IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex('\', Reverse(Replace(@Path, '/','\'))), 0) -1, 200)
    )
  );
end;
```

Example:

```
select dbo.GetFilenameFromPath('C:\ABC\BHDKJF\20240102\Files_20240102_newfile');
```

Returns `Files_20240102_newfile`